# Fell out of the car

Tags: expressions, word-usage, phrasal-verbs

The following is taken from a [website](http://www.ahajokes.com/farm001.html):

> Sir, do you realize your wife **fell out** of the car several miles back?

The expression **fell out** here, as I checked in the dictionary, doesn't make any sense.
 Does it mean **fell off**?

Comment: Please check [fall out](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/fall%20out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have laid the stress on the wrong phrase thereby getting distracted. Look now:

"Sir, do you realize your wife fell **out of** the car several miles back?"

*out of* = *off*
With the substitution, it begins to make sense and you should find it fine.

Answer (score 7):

You get *in* a car and so you get/fall *out*.

You get *on* a bus and so you get/fall *off*.

I have heard that the reason behind this is that you step down *into* cars while you step up *onto* buses.